# Dynamically accessing properties in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, types

I'm new to TypeScript and am trying to access the property of an object by a string. Here is a sandbox showing my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mendel-f1zdg?file=/src/App.tsx

**Code snippet** (App.tsx: 17): `newFlags[event.target.name] = event.target.value;`

**Error**: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ hidden: string; completed: string; }'.

I can make the error go away by adding an if statement like `if(event.target.name === hidden || event.target.name === "completed")` but that solution seems really hard to scale. It seems great if I could use the `<Flag>` type as a variable, but that seems to make TypeScript mad.

Is there a DRY solution to fixing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error makes sense since TS is a compiler, it can't know the exact runtime type of `target.name`, if you are sure it's one of the `Flag` keys, you should specify it:

```
// const flag = event.target.name as 'hidden' | 'completed';
const flag = event.target.name as keyof Flag
return { ...prevFlags, [flag]: event.target.value };
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to declare the handler inline, and take the key from the outer scope instead of from the event target:

```
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(flags)) {
    flagSelectors.push(
      <FlagFiltering
        key={key}
        name={key}
        value={value}
        handleChange={(e) => setFlags({
          ...flags,
          [key]: e.target.value
        })}
      />
    );
  }
```

I'd also recommend avoiding the mutator method `.push` if something more appropriate exists, like `.map`:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">{
      Object.entries(flags).map(([key, value]) => (
          <FlagFiltering
```